# Jquery Focus on File Upload button: 'Split' up the ID so only focuses on button and not text?

Tags: jquery, html, focus

The html code for the ID in question is:

```
<input id="fileImage" value="test" name="fileImage[]" type="file"
multiple="true" onchange="enableUpload()" />
```

The jQuery focus for this is:

```
$("#fileImage").focus();
```

This produces this in the browser:

[image]

I would like to have only the 'Choose Files' button for the focus, not the 'No file chosen' text to the right of the button.

Any way to possibly do this in a somewhat simple manner?